# How we treat tuple parameters and the reduce function in Python 3.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x, parameters, lambda, tuples

Tuple parameter unpacking and the reduce function are no longer available.
I wonder how you convert this code:
suppose sales is a list.

```
(i,v) = reduce( lambda (i_m, v_m),(i,v):
                (i,v) if v>v_m else (i_m, v_m),
                enumerate(sales))
```

Answer (score 0):

Defining a function with argument unpacking is probably the easiest way:

```
>>> def find_max(sale1, sale2):
...     (i_m, v_m), (i,v) = sale1, sale2
...     return (i, v) if v>v_m else (i_m, v_m)
... 
>>> from functools import reduce
>>> sales = 1, 5, 2, 3
>>> i, v = reduce(find_max, enumerate(sales))
>>> i
1
>>> v
5
```

If you want to use `lambda`, you need to index the tuples:

```
i, v = reduce(lambda sale1, sale2: sale2 if sale2[1] > sale1[1] else sale1,
              enumerate(sales))
```

Comment: Wouldn't be more understandable to don't use reduce? this is the idea behind the removal from the standard libraries...